# How do I change a matplotlib patch on a timer?

Tags: python, matplotlib, timer

I have a matplotlib plot that contains a patch. At regular timed intervals, I would like to change the patch (remove the old one and add another patch).

Here's the general setup.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

path1 = Path(vertices, codes)
patch1 = patches.PathPatch(path1, facecolor='white', lw=0.3, fill=False)

ax.add_patch(patch1)
plt.show()
```

after 1 second, remove patch 1 and then

```
path2 = Path(vertices2, codes2)
patch2 = patches.PathPatch(path2, facecolor='white', lw=0.3, fill=False)

ax.add_patch(patch2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation` to paint a new Polygon every second.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

def get_vertices():
    p = np.random.rand(4,2)*.8+.1
    d = p-np.mean(p,axis=0)
    s = np.arctan2(d[:,0], d[:,1])
    return p[np.argsort(s),:]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

patches = []
kw = dict(edgecolor='darkorange', lw=3, facecolor="peachpuff")
patches.append(plt.Polygon(get_vertices(),**kw)) 
# of course  PathPatch(Path(get_vertices())) 
# would also work
ax.add_patch(patches[0])

def update(i):
    patches[0].remove()
    patches[0] = plt.Polygon(get_vertices(),**kw)
    ax.add_patch(patches[0])

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

[image]